# Send log files into azure monitor

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have a log files stored on a server which are constantly updating with log entries. And I would like to upload those files into centralized log management system such as Log Analytics (Azure Monitor). What would be the best approach to accomplish that? How I understand, there one approach is to use "custom logs". So the agent will collect the file and create the custom log entries, but there only 500 custom logs can be created. But how to understand this correctly - only 500 file collections can be done or? Another approach is to use the HTTP Data Collector API. And I can upload 30 MB of data in one go, but I still create a "custom log". So is this "500 custom logs" rule still applies?